# Ensuring C++ destructors are called from a Fortran application

Tags: c++, fortran, destructor

We have a large Fortran application which calls many C++ modules.  I am trying to use the C++ objects' destructors to free resources and close files, but it seems they are not being called when the Fortran program exits.

The Fortran program exits using the `STOP` command.

Do I need to use a different Fortran command to exit, or call the C++ `exit(0)` command from Fortran?

Comment: Are you calling the C++ functions to free the resources before `STOP` is executed?

Comment: At the moment I'm doing nothing - hoping for the garbage collector to kill all the C++ objects (optimistic, I know).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get proper construction/destruction, you just about need the entry point to be on the C++ side.

At least offhand, the simplest approach I can think of that seems at all likely to work would be something like this:

1. set up main in C++, and have it as the entry point.
2. move your current Fortran entry point into a function.
3. call that function from main
4. write a small function in C++ named something like `do_stop()` that just throws an exception
5. in your Fortran, replace STOP with calls to do_stop().

You can either leave the exception uncaught, or have a `try/catch` in main, which can give a slightly more graceful exit (display an error message of your choice instead of something written by the library author saying your program has an error).

Comment: I've been considering making this change for a while, as part of a migration from a FORTRAN program calling C++, to a C++ program calling (gradually reducing amounts) of FORTRAN.  Why is the exception required?

Comment: @MikeSadler: The exception unwinds the stack, invoking destructors as it does so. Then it exits from main, at which point destructors of any globals will be invoked.

Comment: Thanks, @JerryCoffin.  It seems strange that this unwinding of the stack doesn't occur on normal program termination (for example, when exit() is called).  Is there a positive reason for this behaviour?

Comment: @MikeSadler: Yes--`exit()` is basically a C function, that (normally) makes a direct call to the OS to end the process. It knows nothing of destructors or stack unwinding (so you generally don't want to use it in C++ either).